# SignelR Flutter Invalid argument(s): Response Content-Type not supported: [application/json; charset=UTF-8]

Tags: flutter, dart, signalr

I get this exception when trying to use `signalr_client` **[library](https://pub.dev/packages/signalr_client)**:

```
Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Response Content-Type not supported: [application/json; charset=UTF-8]
```

It looks like I can connect to server but not successful in getting response

my Code:

```
  Future<void> openChatConnection() async {
    if (_hubConnection == null) {
      _hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(_serverUrl).build();
      _hubConnection.on("RecieveNotification", null);
    }

    if (_hubConnection.state != HubConnectionState.Connected) {
      await _hubConnection.start();
    }
  }

  Future<void> sendChatMessage(String chatMessage) async {
    if( chatMessage == null ||chatMessage.length == 0){
      return;
    }
    await openChatConnection();
    _hubConnection.invoke("SendNotifications");
  }

  void _handleIncommingChatMessage(List<Object> args){
  ....
  }
```

Appreciate any help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which line of code throws the error?

Comment: @Abion47 On `await _hubConnection.start();` line

Comment: Since the package says it supports JSON, this is either a configuration error or a bug. I'd recommend posting this on the package's issue page on GitHub.

Comment: @Abion47 Isnt the problem about UTF-8?I thought some thing like `setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8")` which we use in Java would to the trick. Any idea?!

Comment: The error message suggests that the response is already a JSON string in UTF-8 encoding, which the package should support but apparently isn't.

Comment: @Abion47 Hmmm...Okay then. I reported this on GitHub. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For those who have response type problem you can just provide an id to the query parameter of your server url just like this:

```
HubConnectionBuilder()
          .withUrl('https://serverUrl.com?id=1')
          .build();
```